# At what point can I edit views in an AlertView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I want to create a generic AlertView Dialog with my custom Dialog Builder. My dialog should have a few TextViews and Buttons which should only be shown if the text was set earlier. My Problem is that I cant find any point where i can safely access those views without getting a NullPointerException.

This is my DialogBuilder class

```
class DialogBuilder : DialogFragment() {

...

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        val inflater = activity?.layoutInflater
        val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.dialog_builder_fragment, null)
        builder.setView(view)
        val dialog = builder.create()
        fillViews()
        initListeners()
        return dialog
    }

...

private fun fillViews() {
        if (headline.isNotBlank()) {
            headline_text_view.text = headline
            headline_text_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        ...
}
```

The exception is thrown in fillViews when I want to set the headline text. I tried it with onViewCreated(), onStart(), ... but nothing seems to work. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your headLine and headline_text_view is inside of dialog_builder_fragment. you should pass view as fillViews function parameter and then call your textviews like that.

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    val inflater = activity?.layoutInflater
    val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.dialog_builder_fragment, null)
    builder.setView(view)
    val dialog = builder.create()
    fillViews(view)
    initListeners()
    return dialog
}
```

...

```
private fun fillViews(view: View) {
    if (view.headline.isNotBlank()) {
        view.headline_text_view.text = headline
        view.headline_text_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I naively thought he knows the context like when you inflate a view in a fragment. Only thing: `view.headline_text_view` does not work but `view.findViewByID<TextView>(R.id.headline_text_view)` does.